# Highcharts Output Data to HTML Table

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am currently working on a highcharts Chart. In a Wrapper I calculate some Data to Display on the Chart, this Data is generated by a random number generator which outputs normal distributed random numbers.

I got them Stored in an Array Called

```
var myArray = [];
```

This Array could have various dimensions, depending on how much random numbers the User wants to generate and display.

This Array is stored in a Private Variable in the Wrapper Method

```
(function (H){
    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'init', function (proceed) {
        var myArray = [],
        var random = new RandomNumber(myForm.max, myForm.min);
        for(var i = 0; i < myForm.numberOfValues; i++){
             myArray[i] = RandomNumber.generate()
        }  
     }
});
```

The Random Number Generator is a own Object that is been used to generate Normal Distributed or Equal Distributed Random Numbers.

How Can I get a Table Now, that is Printed below the Chart and Display me My Data Values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use API to draw table below chart, like in the manual.

Ref:

- http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#add-data-table